# Is there any difference between "commonly" and "normally"?

Tags: meaning, difference

I found the following sentence in my note book.

> It's something you don't hear very commonly.

Can I use "normally" to replace "very commonly"? I looked up them in the dictionary and they have very similar meaning, if not the same.

Comment: Using ***commonly*** in your exact context is a bit of an affectation, since almost all native speakers would use the word ***often*** there. And the sequence ***very normally*** simply isn't idiomatic in English (adverbial ***normally*** isn't normally "gradable" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As adverbs the difference between "commonly" and "normally" is that "commonly" is as a rule; frequently; usually while "normally" is under normal conditions or circumstances; usually; most of the time.

In your example,

> It's something you don't hear very commonly.

Using "commonly" works here, but word often can also be used. And using "very normally" simply isn't idiomatic in English (adverbial normally isn't normally "gradable") - @FumbleFingers

So it basically means you do not hear something very frequently/often

For "normally", you can only use it in sometimes e.g.

> We don't normally use them.

Comment: I disagree that 'commonly' is 'a bit of an affectation'. You should avoid giving opinions such as this.